# Explicit solutions to 2-d Dirac Equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, dirac-equation, discrete

The 2-d Dirac equation without any constants is represented usually as 
$$i*dt (\phi) = D (\phi)$$
where $D = m\sigma_2-i\sigma_1dx-i\sigma_3dy$. 
Where can I find explicit closed form solutions to this equation? If there are none, are there perturbation-like non-exact solutions?

Thanks alot.

Comment: Just try a plane wave solution (as in 4d, where the problem is more difficult but still solved in all textbooks).

Comment: Is there specific solution? I'm wondering how to solve out the 2-vectors though.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think that gives a (2+1) solution, but rather only talks about (1+1) in certain curved manifolds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the Dirac equation $D \psi=0$, we may use the following matrix $D$:

$$D = \begin{pmatrix}  m+\partial_y&\partial_x - \partial_t\\ \partial_x + \partial_t& m-\partial_y\end{pmatrix}  \tag{1}$$

A general solution of the Dirac equation is $\psi = \tilde D \phi$, where $\phi(x,y,t)$ is any 2-row vector, such as $(\partial_t^2-\partial_x^2-\partial_y^2+m^2) \phi = 0$, and $\tilde D $ is the following matrix:

$$\tilde D = \begin{pmatrix}  m-\partial_y&\ -(\partial_x - \partial_t)\\ -(\partial_x + \partial_t)& m+\partial_y\end{pmatrix}  \tag{2}$$

This is because $D \tilde D  = (\partial_t^2-\partial_x^2-\partial_y^2+m^2) \mathbb{Id}$

A general expression for $\phi$ could be obtained with plane waves :

$$\phi(x,y,t) = \int dp_x dp_y f(p) e^{\large i(p_x x + p_y y - \sqrt{p_x^2+p_y^2+m^2}t) }\tag{3}$$
where $f(p)$ is any 2-row vector. The expression for $\psi = \tilde D \phi$ is straightforward.

Comment: What do the p_x and p_y operators represent? Momentum? Thank you.

Comment: $p_x$ and $p_y$ are momenta, and $p_0 = \sqrt{p_x^2+p_y^2+m^2}$ is the energy, but these are not operators, these are usual real commutative quantities. The momentum operators $P_i$ are defined as $-i \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$ (in $\hbar=1$ units) if they apply to a function of space-time like $\phi(x, y,t)$. Applyied to a function of momenta, you have obviously : $P_i f(p) = p_i f(p)$

Comment: What is the domain of momentums we're integrating over? Could you give an example?

Comment: @Xingyou : All real values, from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$. And you may choose any function $f(p_x,p_y)$.

Comment: @Xingyou : Simple example is a pure wave plane solution like : $ \phi_p(x,y,t) =\begin{pmatrix} 1\\0\end{pmatrix}e^{\large i(p_x x + p_y y - \sqrt{p_x^2+p_y^2+m^2}t) }$

Comment: @Xingyou : So, you have : $\psi_p = \tilde D \phi_p=\begin{pmatrix} m-ip_y\\i(p_0-p_x)\end{pmatrix}e^{\large i(p_x x + p_y y - \sqrt{p_x^2+p_y^2+m^2}t) }$